# C#: How to change search directory for dependencies of dynamically loaded assemblies within a dynamically loaded assembly?

Tags: c#, .net

This is convoluted, but here goes:

For integration with another application (in a separate directory), we are dynamically loading one of its assemblies, then using Activator to instantiate an object from that assembly.  The target assembly loads fine, but when creating an instance of the object, it attempts to dynamically load some additional dependencies and fails because it finds a newer version of them in our app dir:

```
var assm = Assembly.LoadFrom("full.path.to.asm"));
var objType = assm.GetType("MyType", true);
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(objType);
```

The `assm` loads fine, and `objType` is obtained.  Exception occurs activating `obj` because it's dependent on an older version of an assembly (which it does have in its directory) but it's finding a newer one in our app directory first and complains about it being the wrong signature.

I tried setting Environment.CurrentDirectory first, but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx) event. In there you can re-direct it to check the other directory for the assembly that is missing.

```
public static object CreateInstance()
{    
    AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += MyResolveEventHandler;
    var assm = Assembly.LoadFrom("full.path.to.asm"));
    var objType = assm.GetType("MyType", true);
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(objType);
}

private static Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Name == "SomeAssemblyIntheOtherFolder")
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName("full.path.to.asm"), "SomeAssemblyIntheOtherFolder.dll");
        return Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
    }
    return null;

}
```

**Update:** A 2nd option is add a assembly binding redirect in your app, this makes the other application use the newer version of the dll that you have instead of the version they where compiled with.

Here is a example of it being done with the library `Common.Logging.dll`, you would put this in your app.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  ...
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.2.0.0" newVersion="3.2.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

What this will do is cause any assemblies that are loaded in your program built to reference any version of the `Common.Logging.dll` library between `0.0.0.0` and `3.2.0.0` to just use `3.2.0.0` instead of the version they where built with.

Comment: Learned something new about the AssemblyResolve event, thanks!